# React array is populated with items, however, upon trying to do the .map function, it says .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to render out the items of an array to the screen and display the items. So I did the .map function. However, when I do the map function, it says that cars.map is not a function. I console logged the items in the car array and it was indeed populated. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? Any advice helps! Thanks!

```
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
```

And where the cars array is being set:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await initCarsInfo();
    setCars(result);
  }, []);

console.log(cars);
```

Here is the console log of cars

```
{cars: Array(2)}cars: Array(2)0: {name: 'Lexus ES', year: 1995, totalMiles: 200000,  …}1: {name: 'Kia Sonota', year: 2005, totalMiles: 250000,  …}length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)[[Prototype]]: Object
```

And where I am mapping it:

```
const getAssetMenuItems = () => {
    {cars && cars.map(carObj => {
      return (
        <MenuItem value="car1">
        <span style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>
          <Typography className={classes.carsName}>{carObj.name}</Typography>
          <Typography>{carObj.year}</Typography>
        </span>
      </MenuItem>
      )
    })}
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I console logged the items in the car array and it was indeed populated* - This is sort of true, but not how you're expecting.

It appears that `cars` from your `initCarsInfo` is returning an object that contains the `cars`, not returning the array directly.

Notice that your console log shows that the value of `cars` is an object: `{cars: Array(2)}`.

You'll need to access that property from the result when setting the state:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  const result = await initCarsInfo();
  setCars(result.cars);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it! @Brian

Answer (score 1):

You need to call like this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await initCarsInfo();
    setCars(result.cars);
}, []);
```